# WPF C#: TreeView (HierarchicalTemplate) with multiple Columns and column headings

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am using a Treeview with a Hierarchical Template and my ItemSource is a ObservableCollection. I want to display 4 properties from the children. Therefore I need 4 columns. I also need two rows. One for the column headings and another one for the Treeview content. The columns from the heading row and the "Treeview" row should always have the same size, even when the Treeview is expanded or collapsed. Therefore I am using the first column with the width auto, the second one with "*", and the columns 3 and 4 should always have a fixed size. That means when I am expanding my Treeview the first column gets bigger and the second column have to be reduced in width. Attached is an image which should explain what I am trying to achieve. When I am defining the "TreeViewGrid" with only two columns (first one width = auto, second one width = *), put the Treeview in column 0 and other textblocks with random texts in the row, the sizing works as I would like to achieve (not in the row with column headings), but then I cannot display more than one property of my Oberservable Collection. And of course there is only one row for the content. When I am expanding the TreeView no more data will be displayed in the further "rows". I hope someone could help here. I am open for any solution here.

Thank you for your time and effort!

[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1NkB.png)

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TreeView.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeView"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="900">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            <Border x:Name="Bd" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                 
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" ></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Column1" ></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Column2" ></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Column3" ></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Column4" ></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="TreeViewGrid" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition   Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TreeView  Width="900" x:Name="treeView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle1}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                                   <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Border Background="Green" CornerRadius="2">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="Green" CornerRadius="2">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Column2"></TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="Green" CornerRadius="2">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="Column3"></TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="Green" CornerRadius="2">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Text="Column4"></TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </DockPanel>

                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
            <!--<TextBlock Text="bla" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>-->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace TreeView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadTreeView();
        }

  
            private void LoadTreeView()
            {
                // Erstelle die Wurzel des TreeViews
                var rootNode = new Node { Name = "Root" };

                // Erstelle die Unterlemente der Wurzel
                var child1 = new Node { Name = "Child 1" };
                var child2 = new Node { Name = "Child 2" };

                // Füge die Unterlemente zur Wurzel hinzu
                rootNode.Children.Add(child1);
                rootNode.Children.Add(child2);

                // Erstelle weitere Kinder für Child 1
                var child1_1 = new Node { Name = "Child 1.1" };
                var child1_2 = new Node { Name = "Child 1.2" };
                child1.Children.Add(child1_1);
                child1.Children.Add(child1_2);

                // Erstelle weitere Kinder für Child 2
                var child2_1 = new Node { Name = "Child 2.1" };
                var child2_2 = new Node { Name = "Child 2.2" };
                child2.Children.Add(child2_1);
                child2.Children.Add(child2_2);

                // Weise die Wurzel als ItemSource der TreeView zu
                treeView.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Node> { rootNode };
            }
    }

    public class Node
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Node> Children { get; set; }

        public Node()
        {
            Children = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you need TreeListView (it is custom control)
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30721/WPF-TreeListView-Control

Comment: Mh I dont think so. How should the TreeListView solve my problem with dynamically sizing of column 1 (growing the width of all TreeviewItems when expanding, shrinking witdh when collapsing) and column 2 (width gets smaller when expanding and bigger when collapsing)? When you expand the Treeview it looks like a normal one. Or am I missing here something?